# How to show listbox context menu on Application key press?

Tags: wpf, listbox, key, contextmenu

I have listbox with context menu, when i press **"Application Key"** its not showing up context menu, it has to work like windows.

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu Name="ZoneIformationList" StaysOpen="true" Background="WhiteSmoke">
      <ContextMenu.BitmapEffect>
         <BitmapEffectGroup/>
      </ContextMenu.BitmapEffect>
      <MenuItem Header="Edit" Name="EditNutritionContextMenu"  />
      <MenuItem Header="Remove" Name="RemoveNutritionContextMenu" />
   </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'when i press "Application Key"'? What is "Application Key"?

Comment: **Appkey** near to right control key

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I deleted that comment when I added my answer... now you've answered it, I'll leave it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices on how to achieve your goal. Either you can create a `Command` that opens the `ContextMenu`, then add a `KeyBinding` with the command and a `KeyGesture` of `ALT + CTRL` to the `InputBindings` of your main window.

You can find out more about the `KeyBinding` class from the [KeyBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) page and the `KeyGesture` class from the [KeyGesture Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx) page at MSDN.

The other option is to add a handler for the `PreviewMouseDown` (or similar) event and monitor whether the `ALT` and `CTRL` keys are being pressed, then programmatically launch the `ContextMenu` control if they are:

```
public void ListBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt && 
(e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        // Open ContextMenu
    }
}
```

Now all that is left is to open the `ContextMenu` from code:

```
if (element.ContextMenu != null )
{
    element.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = element;
    element.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

If the `ContextMenu` is not placed correctly, you can set the placement using the `ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset` and `ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset` properties.

Comment: i have done Commandbinding and Inputbinding in XAML, so when i press **AppKey** Contextmenu is getting open, but when i release the key,it is not visible. How to make it visible eventhough when i release the shortCut key??

Comment: I created a new WPF application based on your situation, added the code that I provided you with and the `ContextMenu` stays open for me after a key press without any problem... I don't know what your problem is, but if you really can't get it to stay open, then please add a new question here on StackOverflow... this one *has* been answered, so please mark it as so.

Comment: please see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332120/wpf-context-menu-disappears-when-key-app-is-released)